# Why am i getting an error when assigning a number to an array?

Tags: javascript

Anyon eknows why im getting an error when setting the value in an array to a variable holding a number?

```
var vCarPosI = vCarsPos.indexOf(vCarPos -1)
var newPos = vCarsPos[vCarPosI] + 1
vCarsPos[vCarPosI] = newPos
```

Comment: `vCarPos` is an array, right? So, why `vCarPos - 1`? it will not result in what you are expecting

Comment: @CalvinNunes - If it has more than one element, yeah. Otherwise, heaven help us, it might work (`[] - 1` => `"" - 1` => `0 - 1` => `-1`, and `[2] - 1` => `"2" - 1` => `2 - 1` => `1`.) :-D

Comment: vCarPos is a number vCarsPos is an Array XD

Comment: @Mystical_Ennio - Oh man, that is **hard** to read. :-)

Comment: Im sorry for that XD

Comment: That code should work, so please see mplungjan's note above about a **runnable** [mcve] using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button); [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/).

Comment: I got the Error... It was the scope XD